# Magento Sales Order tables

Tags: magento

Hello I am trying to get all customer who has bought this certain product. Although I am new to Magento So need your help. This is what I did so far .

```
SELECT o.customer_id,i.product_id ,i.NAME
FROM sales_flat_order_item i INNER JOIN sales_flat_order o 
ON o.entity_id = i.order_id
WHERE o.customer_id IS NOT NULL
AND product_id = '8' OR product_id = '14' OR product_id = '15' OR product_id = '16' ;
```

I need to get only the customers who's payment has been approved for these products(Where can I check that) .

How this will work if the payments were made by recurring payments ?

Please provide some way.

Comment: Cant you run a report on this in the Magento interface?

Comment: sorry, what you mean by report ??

Comment: Actually I have another website(static website not a magento website), And I want only customers who buy these products to access that website

Comment: You mean usisng Report Class?  what is the pseudocode for that i can use as a solution?